# What's a compiled quantum algorithm?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

Many works on quantum algorithms, including [this article](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.100.012305), mention

> a compiled version of (Shor's factoring) algorithm

**What's a compiled quantum algorithm?**

<sub>Meta: and is it worth to create a tag for that? I don't have the required rep.</sub>

Comment: I don't think the "compiled quantum algorithm" is a general term as such. I've only ever heard it in the context of Shor's algorithm, which I've explained below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Nature paper [Oversimplifying quantum factoring](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature12290) explains the concept well.

> All experimental realizations of Shor’s algorithm to date have relied on a further optimization, that of “compiling” the algorithm. This means employing the observation that different bases $a$ in the modular exponentiation lead to different periods of the function $a^x \bmod N$. Some of the periods are both short and lead to a factorization of the composite $pq$. [[arxiv:1301.7007](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7007)]

For instance, in [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphoton.2012.259) the authors claim having done the factorization of $21$ using Shor's algorithm. But the catch is that they had to use the fact that $21 = 3 \times 7$ to choose an "easy" base $a$. So it's not factorization of $21$ in the true sense; they only *verified* the factors. Thus, the qubits needed drastically reduced from $10$ (i.e., $2 + (3/2)\log N$, per [Zalka](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0601097)) to only $2$ qubits! The compilation procedure was also implemented for the [2001 factorization](https://www.nature.com/articles/414883a) of $15$.

It is absolutely crucial to note the following comment by [Smolin *et al.*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7007) here.

> Of course this should not be considered a serious demonstration of Shor’s algorithm. It does, however, illustrate the danger in “compiled” demonstrations of Shor’s algorithm. To varying degrees,
>   all previous factorization experiments have benefited from this artifice. While there is no objection to having a classical compiler help design a quantum circuit (indeed, probably all quantum computers will function in this way), it is not legitimate for a compiler to know the answer to the problem being solved. To even call such a procedure compilation is an abuse of language.